# Create multiple Html tables for the results of commandlets for ConvertTo-Html?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have the following scripts. I wish it returns two html tables, however, both of them return a big html table. Is it a way to create multiple tables using `ConvertTo-Html`?

```
@(dir | select -First 3; Get-Process | select -First 3) | ConvertTo-Html

@{dir = dir | select -First 3; ps = Get-Process | select -First 3} | 
    ConvertTo-Html
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not very elegant, but it works:

```
get-process | select -first 3 | ConvertTo-Html -body (dir | select -first 3 | convertto-html -fragment) |out-file result.html
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

No. `ConvertTo-Html` does not distinguish between different chunks of input lines. If you want to create custom HTML output you'll have to write your own function/cmdlet.